# What is the correct webpack configuration for dealing with 404 refresh errors?

Tags: webpack, build, react-router

I am currently developing a React + Express web application that contains routes. When I go to a route that is not my home page  and I refresh the page, I get a 404 error. There are many posts that solve this problem like the one described here: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/ which I've tried to implement. Here is my understanding of the problem:

1. Go to http://locahost:3000 which loads dist/index.html and dist/bundle.js (which has all the necessary React routes defined)
2. Go to http://localhost:3000/about which is a pre-defined route that serves about.html
3. Refresh the page - you see 404 error, saying that index.html is not defined at http://localhost:3000/about. I understand this is happening because at http://localhost:3000/about, the web application tries to get index.html but it's not found in the `dist/index.html` folder. I believe this is happening because my `dist/index.html` is served in memory from my webpack configuration and there was no "real" `dist/index.html` file created.

Here's my webpack configuration file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // which files should babel be used on
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader', 'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // copy the index.html file to the dist folder so that devServer can serve the static index.html file from dist folder
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ],
  // dist used to serve our application in browser
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 3000,
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
      '/**': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000',
        secure: false
      }
    }
  }
};
```

And my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When using `webpack-dev-server` in combination with `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, from what I've read online, it takes a template index.html file that I've specified and loads it in memory into my `dist` folder. It doesn't physically appear there - rather if you go to `http://localhost:3000/webpack-dev-server` you see the index.html file. It also does the same with my `bundle.js` file that has all my JS code that my `index.html` file references I guess it does it all in memory because what's the point of loading a real index.html file into your dist folder unless you're going to production where you need to serve the files statically.

If I'm correct in understanding this, am I supposed to put an index.html file that references my bundle.js file in development in my dist folder? It would be the same as what I have above except with a `<script>` tag to reference `bundle.js`. It just seems counter-intuitive to me to have an `index.html` file in my `src` folder as well as one in my `dist` folder just for "reloads". Furthermore, why use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` then? what's the point of loading index.html / bundle/js in memory then?

Answer (score 0):

install HtmlWebpackPlugin(html-webpack-plugin) and add index.html solve my same problems

here is webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "[name].[hash:8].bound.js",
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'gsap-learning',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: 'less-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

app.js

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                {/*<Route path="/lesson/:id">*/}
                {/*    <Lessons />*/}
                {/*</Route>*/}
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="renderer" content="webkit">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Gsap-learning</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```